# How should I enable IP forwarding on macOS to set it as gateway?

Tags: macos

I need to set my mbp's IP as a gateway on another machine.
How to set ip forwarding on macOS?
On ubuntu it's just sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1 and all, itt will work.
How to ged rid of this on mac?

Answer (score 3):

The equivalent of that Linux command is to open a Terminal and run the following command on your Mac:

```
sysctl -w net.inet.ip.forwarding=1
```

This will enable IP forwarding on your Mac - essentially making it a network router.

Answer (score 1):

Use Internet Sharing [System Preferences > Sharing]. Specify which to use as 'external' & 'shared'

[image]

It doesn't really require any further user configuration. By default it will use a simple subnet 'one higher' than your existing one - e.g. if you use 192.168.0.x it will set up 192.168.1.x
It will create a DHCP server & NAT to do this pretty seamlessly. It's designed to be user-friendly rather than need CCIE qualifications ;)

Comment: I don't need to create one more internet interface, will it be possible to use only terminal as in ubuntu?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by that. You can't share a single interface, you must go through one to another.

Comment: I mean my MBA has only one interface - wifi. Sharing by such way needs selecting two interfaces. And I'd like to use this only interface as gateway.

Comment: You can't share a single interface.